# Capturing a given window using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Could anyone provide me the code for capturing a given window in WPF application?
I have implemented it in Windows Form application, but its getting messy in WPF.

Comment: what do you mean by capturing?

Comment: taking snapshots continously..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to save an image of the window you can create a RenderTargetBitmap object and render the window to it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Captures a controls visual and saves it to the file system.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="visual">A reference to the <see cref="Visual"/> that you want to capture.</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The file name that you want the image saved as.</param>
void CaptureImage(Visual visual, string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        File.Delete(fileName);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Width, (int)Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(this);
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
        encoder.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Which is used with the line.

```
CaptureImage(this, @"c:\temp\screencap.png");
```